# Como revuelvo el error de indice fuera de la matriz?

Tags: c#

Como revuelvo el error de indice fuera de la matriz?

Estoy realizando un programa sencillo sobre leer 5 números y guardarlo en un vector, pero al momento de ejecutar el programa me sale el error de que el índice está fuera de la matriz.
Por favor, ¿pueden decirme donde esta el error?

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   class Program
   {
    public static void Main()
     {
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Pruebas con vectores");
    int ind = 1;

    int[] arr1 = new int[5];
    int[] arr2 = new int[5];
    Console.WriteLine("Digite 5 numeros ");
    while (ind <= arr1.Length) {

    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arr1[ind]);
      ind = ind+1;  
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Digite 5 numeros ");
    while (ind<=arr2.Length) {
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arr2[ind]);
        ind = ind + 1;
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberias compatir tu codigo, los que aportamos o lo intentamos varias veces no somos adivinos como para entender tu error.

Comment: Sii ya acabo de agregarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay dos puntos que debes tener en cuenta

- Los array comienzan en el indice cero
- Cuando usas el `Length` no usas el igual porque este representa la cantidad de item, por eso se usa solo el `<` o sino al length le debes restar uno

Aqui el codigo arreglado

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pruebas con vectores");

    int ind = 0;
    int[] arr1 = new int[5];
    int[] arr2 = new int[5];

    Console.WriteLine("Digite 5 numeros ");

    while (ind < arr1.Length) {
       int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arr1[ind]);
      ind = ind+1;  
    }

    ind = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Digite 5 numeros ");

    while (ind < arr2.Length) {
    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arr2[ind]);
        ind = ind + 1;
    }


}
```